# Printing int variable in float format

Tags: c, gcc, printf

I'm using `gcc` to compile this:

```
int a=1;
printf("%d\n",a);
printf("%f\n",a);
printf("%f\n",(float)a);
```

I get:

> 1
>   0.000000
>   1.000000

Why does the implicit conversion give a wrong output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no conversion.
printf is not a function that accepts a float. It is a function that accepts an argument list that could be of any type.

The compiler assumes that a float was given and you are seeing basically undefined behaviour.

There is no mechanism that will parse your input string and then apply custom conversion on each parameter. You should be very careful with what you pass to printf cause exploits can be opened this way.

Answer (score 2):

Because a `double` (which `%f` expects) probably is larger than an `int` on your platform. There is no "implicit conversion"; it will pass an `int` as the second argument and `printf()` will read a `double`.

This is undefined behavior by the way, don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
int a=1;
//something
printf("%f\n",a);
```

there is no implicit conversion, rather an inappropriate usage of format specifier, which produces  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Related: `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.1, `fprintf()` function

> If any argument is
>   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Because using the wrong format specifier is undefined behavior. It could print anything.

In realty it depends on the ABI and how it passes float arguments versus int arguments. In many systems floating point values are passed in registers reserved for this use, while int values are passed in different registers. This seems to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no conversion in the 2nd `printf`. You are invoking Undefined Behaviour by mismatching the conversion specifier (the `"%f"`) and the type of value (an `int`).

Answer (score 0):

By doing `printf("%f\n",a);` you are invoking an undefined behaviour.
Whereas, by doing `printf("%f\n",(float)a);` you type cast the integer `a` so it prints the value as float as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` obtains its parameters in their own binary format. The *format string* is actually a description how to interpret such binary data. If this *format string* doesn't correspond to the actually provided binary data the behaviour is undefined at best.